Creating a code block in Staging Ground includes one additional character after the text selection
When you edit a question in the Staging Ground to convert a text selection into a multiline code block by using the "Code block" button (or pressing CTRL-M), a code block will be entered which contains one additional character from after the current text selection. This can result in cutting of one letter from the next word.
When you select a word like this:

It will result in the following code block:

Already here, you can see that an additional whitespace is added/picked inside the code block content.
But when you select a word including one addition space after it like this:

it will result in the following code block:

As you see, the letter t is cut off from the following word "these" and put inside the code block, which was not intended. This is specially problematic when you select full lines (including the line break at the end) to convert to a code block.
I have tested this behavior with:

Opera One (version: 113.0.5230.86), Linux, Chromium version:127.0.6533.120
Firefox 130.0.1 (64-bit), Linux, Build ID 20240913135723

I haven't tested it with a browser on any other OS.

This is true of anywhere that uses the stacks editor, such as answers here on meta for those with the setting enabled.
